# How to make animated overlay pin on map Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-maps

I am displaying number of icon on map, now i want those icon should blink, please guide me how to that.
can we use two image for light and dim, but main problem is that how to change that overlay image or how to put animation on that image to blink.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help me, i tried and researched lot but i did not get success...

Comment: the below answer really helped you which you accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using ImageView for icon then put below xml in drawable and use as a Imageview src.

```
<animation-list   android:id="@+id/my_animation" android:oneshot="false" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="150" />
 </animation-list>
```

and use below code to set animation

```
 ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =    (AnimationDrawable)img.getDrawable();
 frameAnimation.setCallback(img);
 frameAnimation.setVisible(true, true);
 frameAnimation.start();
```

Comment: Thanks to help me..  But main problem is that once i am adding the overlay item and when displaying on map that time how to get the object of that default marker drawable?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a custom view and use it as a Map Overlay.

Tell Its OnDraw() to invallidate whole view after 500ms and everytime drawing again use alternative image.

This link might be helpful to you:

http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/03/19/tutorial-2-mapview-google-map-hit-testing-for-display-of-popup-windows/